# How do I display a Hindi font on Android 2.3 emulator?

Tags: android, fonts, hindi

I wish to display a Hindi font on my Android 2.3 emulator by rooting the device. How do I rename the existing font (DroidSansFallback.ttf) to DroidHindi.ttf? I get an error when I try: "Read only file". How might I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because it is located in the ROM?

What you should be doing is placing the DroidHindi.ttf file in the assets folder and loading it using

```
 Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "DroidHindi.ttf");
 textView.setTypeface(t);
```

Comment: I used your code and I am still not able to display hindi font although there is no error in the code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

use a non unicode font and try the below one.

```
Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "DroidHindi.ttf");
 textView.setTypeface(t);
```